# How to become an Google appengine admin user (login: admin in app.yaml)

Tags: google-app-engine

I downloaded an google app engine application from github.
I can start the development server, but cannot access the /admin/ pages as defined below.

```
handlers:   
- url: /admin/.*  
  script: main.app  
  login: admin
```

How can one user be recognized by the Dev or production server as an admin ?

Answer (score 5):

For the production server, the user must have access to the admin console:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/index

Goto https://appengine.google.com, click permission and add their email address.

Role definitions are here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/roles

On the dev server, "login" using the /_ah/login URL and check the 'admin' checkbox to simulate an admin user login:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_Users

Comment: adding /_ah/login after localhost:8888 worked for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In the devappserver there's a checkbox for login as an admin (See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_Users).

In production, you need to be added to the admin list in the Permissions tab (See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/roles).